# Is it valid to patent exclusive or of a set of vectors?

Tags: patentability, us20130242109

My question is in regards to this [patent](https://www.google.com/patents/US20130242109?dq=US20130242109+A1&hl=en&sa=X&ei=aX99U_vdOoOF8gXR3YGYAw&ved=0CDkQ6AEwAA). They are claiming that their method of exclusive or'ing a set of vectors to estimate camera network topology. Is it fundamentally valid to patent such a method for anything?

As I can see, all this patent claims is that:
If one cameras field of view (window), is occupied, and simulatenously another cameras field of view isn't, then they are not connected.

I think this is just logic which can be applied to anything. What do you guys think?

Answer (score 1):

The document you reference is a patent application, *not* a granted patent. I see the same inventors do have an issued patent [US8396250](http://www.google.com/patents/US8396250) based on the same disclosure. The application you have referenced is a follow-on application that seems to attempting to get greater coverage then they got in US8396359. That issued patent has a much longer and narrower claim 1 that puts more specificity into what they and the examiner thought was new and not obvious.

Comment: I think that it is also important to note that although the patent references Australian Provisional Patent Application No. 2006906433, the new US application never defines the terms "sensed data window" or "corresponding region", which figure strongly in the independent claims. I believe the application is poorly written and will not be granted due to significant ambiguity in the description.